# Any way to modify xml prefix generated by JAXB without modify code?

Tags: namespaces, xsd, jaxb, schema

I am using JAXB to marshall the object to xml, now the xml generated is like

```
<QueryServiceElement xmlns="http://tools.ding.com/query">
</QueryServiceElement>
```

What I want is:

```
<ts1:QueryServiceElement xmlns:ts1="http://tools.ding.com/query">
</ts1:QueryServiceElement>
```

As the code has been shared with multiple places, so I can't  use mapper property in the JAXB Marshaller, and my jaxb also not support the mapper property, it throws exception, is there any way to do this by just modify xsd files or jaxb schema binding?

I have try many ways, but they are all not work.

Comment: I fixed your formatting.  XML (code in general) can be entered and displayed as-is by indenting 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, the act of generating (or even using) namespace prefixes in the resultant XML is completely up to the marshaller and has nothing to do with the XSD.

http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/customizing_jaxb has a good explanation of how to deal with custom namespace prefix generation. from your question, it seems you're already aware of this.  it is a JAXB 2.0+ feature, so if your jaxb implementation doesn't support it, maybe it's time to get a later version?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, it's helpful. While the jaxb version I am using is 2.1 infact, but after debug, I found the implementation doesn't support mapper property, it throws the PropertyException, and I can't update it, while because I am marshalling the xml into a SoapElement, then after that I can reset some prefix in the SoapElement to solve this.